# How to encode a string to UTF8 and then display it correctly in html?

Tags: java, rest, jsp

I have a program, in which a table is shown on the screen. The content is displayed correctly as long as there are no accents.

This is my code

```java
StringBuffer sBuff = new StringBuffer();
if(!("CSV".equalsIgnoreCase(exportFormat) || "HTML".equalsIgnoreCase(exportFormat))){
        sBuff.append("<p title=\""+displayparseado+"\">");
        sBuff.append(displayparseado);
        sBuff.append("</p>");
}
else{
        sBuff.append(display);
}
```

I have also tried parsing the string.

```java
byte arr[] = display.getBytes("UTF-8");
String displayparseado = new String(arr);
```

Expected output: Descripción de prueba.

Actual output:

[image]

A note; I can not use external libraries.

Comment: Are you using thymeleaf at front-side?

Comment: It is looks like you escape your `sBuff`. Don't do it,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html) to escape your String for html. This did a good job for me till now.

Comment: Thank you but I can not use external libraries.